# Transferring files from remote server modified in last week

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a small bash script where I'm trying to get jpg files from a remote server using rsync. The issue I'm facing is an 'Argument list too long' error. Filtering using *x.jpg works so I'm guessing the error means there are too many files? I only need files added/updated in the last week if that makes things easier.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -avzq -e "ssh -p 2223" root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/pictures/*.jpg  /home/http/web2/images/
```

Being completely new to using Linux I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the accepted answer here as a solution:
https://serverfault.com/questions/538767/how-to-rsync-files-folders-from-a-specific-date-forward

but really not sure if this is the best way to do this in my case

```
rsync -avzq -e "ssh -p 2223" --files-from=<(ssh -p 2223 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'find /home/pictures/ -mtime -7 -type f -exec basename {} \;') root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/home/pictures/  /home/http/web2/images/
```

but it seems to work